# has_many join form with collection checkboxes not saving more than one checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, checkbox, nested-attributes, form-for

I am working on a form for a editorial calendar app.  I have two things going out that are pretty similar and not working.

Working with 3 models: Platforms, Posts and Calendars. They are join tables. Platform <=> Post, Post <=> Calendars

```
Post/new & Post/edit form:
    <div class="container">
  <div class="form-field">
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, required: true %> <br>
    Title is required.
  </div>

  <div class="form-field">
    <%= f.label :content%>
    <%= f.text_area :content%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-field">
    <%= f.label :link %>
    <%= f.text_field :link %>
  </div>

  <div class="file-field">
    <%= f.label :picture%>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, id: :post_picture%>
  </div>

  <div class="file-field">
    <%= f.label :finalized %>
    <%= f.radio_button :finalized , true%>
    <%= f.label :finalized, "Yes" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :finalized, false %>
    <%= f.label :finalized, "No" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %> <br>

  <div class="form-field">
    <%= f.fields_for :platform_attributes do |platform| %>
    <%= platform.label :platform, "Social Platforms"%>
    <%= platform.collection_check_boxes :platform_ids, Platform.all, :id, :name %> <br> <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4> Or Create a new platform: </h4>
    <%= platform.label :platform, 'New Platform'%>
    <%= platform.text_field :name%> <br> <br>
  </div>
  <% end %>


  <%= f.submit%>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

My post controller is handling the checkboxes issue, and the "schedule post" issue. It will only allow me to schedule for one calendar, and it does not save the updates and add additional calendars.

```
 Posts Controller:
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :schedule_post, :destroy]

    def new
        @posts = current_user.posts.select {|p| p.persisted?}
        @post = current_user.posts.build
        @platforms = Platform.all
      end

      def edit
        @calendars = current_user.calendars
        @platforms = Platform.all
      end

      def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        if @post.save
          redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
          redirect_to new_post_path
        end
      end

      def update
        @post.update(post_params)
        if @post.save
          redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Your post has been updated.'
        else
          redirect_to edit_post_path(@post)
        end
      end

      def schedule_post
        @calendar_post = CalendarPost.new(calendar_post_params)
        if @calendar_post.save
          binding.pry
          redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
          render 'show'
        end
      end

      private
      def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end

      def set_calendars
        @calendars = current_user.calendars
      end

      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :link, :finalized, :picture, :user_id, :platform_attributes => [:platform_ids, :name])
      end

      def calendar_post_params
        params.require(:calendar_post).permit(:post_id, :calendar_id, :date, :time)
      end
    end
```

I want the user to be able to add a post to multiple platforms and multiple calendars because of the versatility of what someone may need.

I also have my setter in my Post model.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :calendar_posts
  has_many :calendars, through: :calendar_posts
  has_many :platform_posts
  has_many :platforms, through: :platform_posts
  belongs_to :user




 def platform_attributes=(platform_attributes)
        if platform_attributes['platform_ids']
          platform_attributes.platform_ids.each do |id|
            platform = Platform.find(id: id)
            self.platforms << platform
          end
        end
        if platform_attributes['name'] != ""
          platform = Platform.find_or_create_by(name: platform_attributes['name'])
          self.platforms << platform
        end
      end
```

thoughts? why are they not saving to more than one calendar or more than one platform if they choose to have more than one?

Here is the updated code... and more of what I know about these changes and what is happening.

My submit button is not working for some odd reason on my form, so I'm trying to get the params submitted but it won't even route to give me params even if I raise them, nothing is happening.

On the form you can choose checkboxes or add in a platform. If you add in a platform it creates that one but it does not also save the other ones you selected. If you go to edit the post, and click submit with changes, no page loads at all and nothing is happening in log. It's just idle.

Comment: Hi. Can you have a look in your output (either console or logfile) and show us what comes through as params when you post this form with multiple platforms selected? That can often help us figure out what's going wrong. Also - what html is generated by that form? Note: please edit your question and add the new code there, rather than posting it in comments, because code-formatting in comments is nigh unreadable :P cheers :)

Comment: Also: I notice that you don't have `:platform_ids` in your permit/require method... you might need that.

Comment: Just edited the above. I'm trying to figure out why the submit buttons aren't working and once I can do that I can get the other information over. If you see something that may be preventing the buttons from submitting let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.fields_for :platform_attributes do |platform| %>
```

assumes you are creating one platform... it says "these are the fields for this platform"

but `platform_ids` is intended to be a selection of a set of platforms... and probably should be outside of the `fields_for` section (which should only surround the `name` field).

try something like the following:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <%= f.label :platform_ids, "Social Platforms"%>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :platform_ids, Platform.all, :id, :name %> <br> <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :platform_attributes do |platform| %>
     <h4> Or Create a new platform: </h4>
      <%= platform.label :name, 'New Platform'%>
      <%= platform.text_field :name%> <br> <br>
    <% end %>
    <%# end fields_for %>
  </div>
```

Also you'll need to update permit/require appropriately eg

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :link, :finalized, :picture, :user_id, :platform_ids, :platform_attributes => [:name])
  end
```

Note: not tested - bugs are left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thank you for the info! I got this to work with these changes, and some additional changes to the setter/getter attribute methods, and changes in controller.